# iOS DateFormatter giving nil ,When device Timezone and region changes

Tags: ios, swift, date, nsdateformatter

I have a date in string like this

```
let time = "Wed Oct 10 12:22:32 UTC 2018"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EE MM dd HH:mm:ss zz yyyy"
let rawDate = dateFormatter.date(from: time) // GETTING rawDate
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMM yyyy, h:mm a"
guard let date = rawDate else { return "" } // rawDate NIL HERE
let time = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
```

It works fine in my timezone Mumbai and region India. But when i'm changing it to some other region and timezone, rawDate is getting nil.

What's wrong i'm doing?

**P.S:** Please give a generic answer, No fixed **timezone** or **Locale** is needed.

**Update:** As the duplicate reference consist **en_US** posfix, This doesn't make code generic, if I use **en_GB** or something else the data will be incorrect.

Comment: Yes, you need a hardcoded locale of `en_US_POSIX`. This is required when parsing a fixed format date string. You can't expect a string with English names in it to be parsed in a non-English locale. And this special locale also deals with various user preferences such as 12/24-hour setting. Please read the duplicate and its answers. This is only needed when creating a `Date` from a `String`, not the other way around.